# Ramda Pass "Maybe" Error Message Through Chain Calls

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, fantasyland, ramda-fantasy

Lets say I have bunch of functions returns Just or Nothing values and I want to chain them together like this;

```
var a = M.Just("5").map(function(data){
    return 1;
}).chain(function(data){
/*Make some operation return Just or Nothing */
    console.log(data);
    return M.Just(2);
}).chain(function(data){
/*Make some operation return Just or Nothing */
    console.log(data);
    return M.Nothing("Reason 1");
}).chain(function(data){
/*Make some operation return Just or Nothing */
    console.log(data);
    return M.Nothing("Reason 2");
}).getOrElse(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    return "Message";
});

console.log(a());
```

Output:

```
>     1
>     2
>     undefined
>     Message
```

In this above code since it is failing at step where function returns M.Nothing("Reason 1") it does not go through over other functions which is what I expected. I believe there is no valid constructor for Nothing that takes parameters. Is there a way to get this failure message at the end of the execution ? I have tried this in folktale as-well, does it related with fantasy land spec?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that both `Maybe` and `Either` embody short circuiting. But while the latter can provide an error message, the former can not.

Comment: And if you want to collect multiple errors, look to something like a `Validation` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Either monad for this purpose as it is stated in docs.

> The Either type is very similar to the Maybe type, in that it is often used to represent the notion of failure in some way.

I modified the example you gave with Either monad below.

```
var R = require('ramda');
var M = require('ramda-fantasy').Either;

var a = M.Right("5").map(function(data){
return 1;
}).chain(function(data){
/*Make some operation return Just or Nothing */
console.log(data);
return M.Right(2);
}).chain(function(data){
/*Make some operation return Just or Nothing */
console.log(data);
return M.Left("Reason 1");
}).chain(function(data){
/*Make some operation return Just or Nothing */
console.log(data);
return M.Left("Reason 2");
});
console.log(a);
console.log(a.isLeft);
```